# Get existing website's CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, media-queries, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet that reads a website's CSS media queries and adds CSS rules depending on the result. But I usually can't even access a page's CSS file. Here's what I've tried so far (this is all in-page JS code that assumes the presence of JQuery):

```
var styleSheet = document.styleSheets.item(0);
var rules = styleSheet.cssRules;
```

This fails with

> Exception: The operation is insecure.

I'm using Firefox and think that this approach usually works in other browsers, but I need this to work across browsers. I can't enable `JSONP` or `CORS` on the server because I don't have access to the server. So I take a different tack.

```
$.ajax({
  url: styleSheet.href,
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('data: '+data+", textStatus: "+textStatus+"\nObject: "+data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    console.error("Failed. jqXHR: "+JSON.stringify(jqXHR)+"\ntextStatus:"+textStatus+"\nerror: "+error);
  }
});
```

This returns `200` every time, but works very infrequently, and gives me no information of why it fails:

> Failed. jqXHR: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
>
> textStatus: error
>
> error:

(I also tried a plain `$.get`, but hoped the above would tell me why it was failing). If you know how to get more info out of a request, let me know.

Because I'm looking for media queries, I need access to the CSS file and can't just look at elements' calculated CSS.

I'm not trying to change the CSS file, just apply apply new CSS to elements, so I don't see why it should be considered insecure.

Finally, the fact that I can clearly see a page's CSS in the style editor or by navigating to the URL I get from `styleSheet.href` means that it should be accessible programatically. If possible, a solutions that works on `https` pages as well would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that (in FF at least) you can't read styleSheets cross domain using unprivileged Javascsript (like in bookmarklets). It is the same limitation as AJAX. There is no "direct" solution. You'll have to work around it by using a proxy or by using privileged javascript (like in an addon or userscript).

Here is a related snippet of code I have used which accepts the limitation.

```
function getStyle() {
  var r = [];
  for ( var i=0; i < d.styleSheets.length; i++ ) {
    try { // trying to read cross domain sheets can throw error
      var classes = d.styleSheets[i].rules || d.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
      for ( var x=0; x < classes.length; x++ ) r.push(classes[x].cssText || classes[x].style.cssText);
    } catch(e){}
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: This has the benefit of not crashing, but doesn't work in FF (as you stated). What do you mean by using a proxy?

Comment: A 3rd party web page that will fetch the contents of another web page and return it to your script using either JSONP or CORS.

Comment: Wouldn't that third party page be constrained by the same limitations in that it would have to use privileged javascript itself?

Comment: My understanding is that the page I am trying to access has to enable CORS or JSONP by altering the server's response headers. Since I can't alter those headers, I don't see how my third party page could access the contents of that page any better than the above code already does.

Comment: Server side code is not encumbered by security policies designed for web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The operation is insecure because of browser security policies.  Browsers will restrict you to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), unless [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://enable-cors.org/) is enabled on the requested page. This means that you cannot request resources from another webpage (i.e. stylesheets) unless it explicitly allows you to.

You can get around this by writing your bookmarklet as a browser extension, which is not restricted to the Same Origin Policy.  For example, Chrome Extensions can make Cross Origin XMLHttpRequests (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html).